# Redirect all pages with missing Itemid to home page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Most of the pages on my website have missing Itemid values, that's no number attached to the Itemid key.

I want any pages with a missing Itemid to redirect to the home page. Here are a few examples of URLs:

```
 http://www.xyz.com/?page=16&&option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=
 http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_news&view=detail&n_id=366&Itemid=
 http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_car&view=search&Itemid=
 http://www.xyz.com/index.php?option=com_car&view=product&Itemid=&id=34&vid=133
```

How do I redirect these pages where the Itemid value is missing to the home page?

I have tried some permutations and combinations but all in vain; please help if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo may try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=(&|$)
RewriteRule .*  http://homepage.com/?      [L]
```

Remove the last question mark `?` if you want to keep the query in the substitution URL.

Comment: yes it works, thanks... i have changed to [R=301,L] or shall i use [L] as referred... i basically need 301 redirect of all the urls with missing itemid .  thnx

Comment: Yes, you can use a permanent redirect `[R=301,L]` with no problem. I missed that part of your comment.